# Moving disks from HP DL360g5 to DL380g6 with Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have DL360G5, with E200i array controller, 128MB cache + BBWC. It is running Windows 2008, as a member of the domain.
I have a total of 4 disks there: 2x72GB SAS, 2x300GB SAS, with two mirrors, one for system, one for data.
I'd like to move all those disks to a never DL380 G6, with P410i, 256MB cache + BBWC.
The disks itself should be compatible and P410i should recognize old logical volumes without problems.
The question is: will the Windows 2008 will be able to boot after swapping disks to DL380G6?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should work. The RAID metadata is stored on the disks, and the format is the same between the controllers involved.

Please [update firmware](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) on all of the components before you do this.

As for Windows, this constitutes a platform change, so I don't know the full implications. But the system should technically boot.